# Cast Generic with derived type to generic with parent type

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

I have a base class:

```
public abstract class InputParserBase<TInputData> : ServerComponentBase
        where TInputData : SolverDataBase
    {
        public abstract TInputData Parse(ClientInputData task);               
    }
```

and a child:

```
public class BinomTaskParser : InputParserBase<BinomTaskData>
    {

        public override BinomTaskData Parse(ClientInputData inputData)
        {//Some stuff
        }
    }
```

BinomTaskData is inherited from SolverDataBase

My second class is in another assembley and i load it in runtime. And the thing is that i can have different childs with another types, derived from SolverDataBase. I want to load them and store like this:

```
var result = new List<InputParserBase<SolverDataBase>>();
var parser = (InputParserBase<SolverDataBase>)AssembleyHelper.CreateInstance(typePair, null);
result.Add(parser);
```

But get a cast exception. What am i doing wrong and how can i implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classes are invariant so the cast is invalid. You could create an interface:

```
public interface IInputParser<out T> where T : SolverDataBase
{
    T Parse(ClientInputData);
}
```

and implement it in the base class or in each subclass:

```
public abstract class InputParserBase<TInputData> : ServerComponentBase, IInputParser<TInputData>
        where TInputData : SolverDataBase
{
    public abstract TInputData Parse(ClientInputData task);
}
```

then you can create a list like:

```
var result = new List<IInputParser<SolverDataBase>>();
var parser = (IInputParser<SolverDataBase>)AssembleyHelper.CreateInstance(typePair, null);
result.Add(parser);
```

Comment: Hmm, i think i got magic of covariance, but, as i understood, this only works for return types. And what about method parameter?How can i make ClientInputData also a generic type and then make a List<IInputParser<SolverDataBase,ClientInputBase>>? I can't get it work

Comment: Lee, i have worked aroung co- and contravariance in c# and understood how it works. But the trouble is that i also need covariance on arguments and, as i understood, i can't cheat the compiler. Is there any workaround to make argument of my Parse method also covariant?